# Почему не отрабатывает mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql

Отрабатывает только последний case, а первые 2 нет. Уже всею голову сломал. Помогите пожалуйста.

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS queue_log;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `queue_log` AFTER insert ON `queue_log`

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

CASE WHEN queue_log.`event` = 'COMPLETEAGENT' THEN UPDATE calls SET calls.laststep = 'answered' WHERE calls.uniqueid = NEW.callid;
END CASE;

CASE WHEN queue_log.`event` = 'COMPLETECALLER' THEN UPDATE calls SET calls.laststep = 'answered' WHERE calls.uniqueid = NEW.callid;
END CASE;

CASE WHEN queue_log.`event` = 'RINGNOANSWER' THEN DELETE FROM queue_log WHERE queue_log.callid = NEW.callid;
END CASE;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Точно не отрабатывает? Попробуйте для каждой `case`-ветки выводить сообщение об ошибке (в духе `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'case COMPLETEAGENT', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1000;`) и подергайте таблицу, на которой висит триггер из консоли.

Comment: Не мешало бы приложить DDL таблицы `queue_log`.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего нужно отметить, что триггер вообще написан неправильно. Конструкция `CASE/WHEN` используется иначе. Скорее всего имелось в виду следующее:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS queue_log;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `queue_log` AFTER insert ON `queue_log`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  CASE NEW.`event` # не `queue_log`, а именно NEW
    WHEN 'COMPLETEAGENT' THEN UPDATE calls SET calls.laststep = 'answered' WHERE calls.uniqueid = NEW.callid;
    WHEN 'COMPLETECALLER' THEN UPDATE calls SET calls.laststep = 'answered' WHERE calls.uniqueid = NEW.callid;
    WHEN 'RINGNOANSWER' THEN DELETE FROM queue_log WHERE queue_log.callid = NEW.callid;
  END CASE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Но даже c правильным `CASE/WHEN` триггер работать не будет, поскольку в третьей ветке происходит удаление из той же таблицы, операция над которой запускает триггер.

Самое удивительное в том, что в вопросе заявлено, что как раз третья ветка отрабатывает, несмотря на обе проблемы.

Comment: Так когда добавляется строка с RINGNOANSWER он ее сам же и удаляет т.к. это не нужная запись. А строки COMPLETEAGENT и COMPLETECALLER нормально добавляются. Он их не стирает, потому что они условию RINGNOANSWER  не соответствуют. Спасибо сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Работает!!!

Comment: @Andrey А ведь не должно.

Comment: Так если AFTER insert, то сначала добавляет, а потом уже эту же запись удаляет по критерию WHEN 'RINGNOANSWER', а не всё подряд.

Comment: А можно как-то более элегантно поступить нежели удалять после добавления. Как то игнорить по критерию.
Спасибо!

Comment: @Andrey Можно. Не нужно её вообще добавлять. В том месте, где она добавляется, можно сразу проверить на 'RINGNOANSWER' и просто ничего не делать.